# getting batch request from gmail api

Tags: javascript, gmail, sails.js

messageList we are sending message ids

```
function getGmailMessagesBatch(oauth2Client, messagesList) {
    var batchBody = \ [\];
    var indReq = '';
    if (oauth2Client && oauth2Client.credentials && oauth2Client.credentials.access_token) {
        /*Generating the request body for the batch request
        according to gmail api docs for batching multiple api calls into one request
        each request should a part of the request body, so doing that below
        refer to gmail api docs for details info*/
        \
        _.each(messagesList, function(eachMessage) {
            indReq = '';
            indReq = "--request_boundary\\n" +
                "Authoriz
            ation: Bearer "+oauth2Client.credentials.access_token+"\\
            n "+
            "Content-Type: application/http\\n\\n" +
            "GET /gmail/v1/users/" + data.userEmail + "/messages/" + eachMessage.id + "\\n";
            batchBody.push(indReq);
        })
        batchBody.push("--request_boundary--\\n");
        batchBody = batchBody.join('\\n');
        //Sending the batch request
        rp({
                uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/batch/gmail/v1',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    "content-type": "multipart/mixed; boundary=request_boundary"
                },
                body: batchBody,
                resolveWithFullResponse: true
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                /*The response is stringified & the response to each of the api calls present
                in the batch request is seperated by a boundary which is present in the content
                type header of the response,therefore we need to parse the response to
                obtain the actual data*/
                var parsedResponse = parseBatchResponse(response);
                return cb(null, parsedResponse);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                sails.log.error('Error in getting messages async in eachseries', error, data);
                return cb('Unexpected error!');
            })
    } else {
        sails.log.error('Access token missing to sync emails using gmail api', data);
        return cb('Authorization failure!');
    }
}
```

in the parsedResponse the error i am getting is

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "gmail.googleapis.com",
          "method": "caribou.api.proto.MailboxService.GetMessage"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

i am expecting to get messages from gmail of specific ids